# Python: & operator not returning False based on the first argument

Tags: python, if-statement, evaluation

Why is the following expression returning an error instead of a False. Following the documentation http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations the expression should return False based on the first argument.

```
blubb = None
print (False & (len(blubb[u'blubb2']) > 0))
```

Comment: Perhaps you have meant `print (False and (len(blubb[u'blubb2']) > 0))`?

Comment: Sorry, yes. But why isn't then python throwing a syntax error?

Comment: Because `&` is an operator of bitwise `AND`. It compares bits of values on both sides, and returns a value that has particular bit equal to `1` if both of values had bit on that position equal to `1`, `0` otherwise.

Comment: It does throw an error for me. "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Because `blubb` is not a dictionary, you defined it to `None`

Comment: Downvote for guessing operators

Answer (score 4):

The `&` operator is a bitwise *and*: it evaluates both operands. Use the `and` operator for a logical *and* that short-circuits (i.e. stops evaluating as soon as an operand is not true).